# Writing a local file through shell command in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell

I am trying to write a file via shell command in Rails..

Basically I have this:

```
def self.collect_videos

  %x[cd public/videos/ && exec viddl-rb http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0]
     sleep(30)
end
```

viddl is essentially this: https://github.com/rb2k/viddl-rb

It works fine just from rails console, but not when called as a function from Rails app..

How to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you change cd public/videos/ to it's absolute url? (e.g. /home/ubuntu/app/current/public/videos)

Comment: does not work.. works in console, but not as function

Comment: Is viddl-rb in path when running as app? Try full path.

Comment: Tips is to do (...commands...) > 2>&1 > /tmp/log so that you see whats happening. Also why use exec and sleep?

Comment: everything worked after I added absolute path to viddl-rb. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered thanks to Mattias Wadman. Could not mark comment as answer though.